# Making Bingo Game: How to check if element in array is duplicate and change it's value without being duplicate again to other element

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

Our teacher wants us to make a bingo game that will generate a random bingo card. My problem is that it makes duplicate, the bingo card is not supposed to have a duplicate number per row. I created an algorithm but it is wrong, There are times that when it changes an element, it will duplicate the other element from the array but my loop/algorithm cannot detect it.

```
// Bingo numbers
int B[16] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
int I[16] = { 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 };
int N[16] = { 31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45 };
int G[16] = { 46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60 };
int O[16] = { 61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75 };

// row and column of 2d Array
int row = 1;
int column = 1;

// counter
int x = 1;

// Bingo Card that will be given (randomly generated)
int bingocard[6][6];
// Pattern X to win Bingo
int bingoPattern[] = { bingocard[1][1], bingocard[1][5], bingocard[2][2], bingocard[2][4], bingocard[3][3], bingocard[4][2], bingocard[4][4], bingocard[5][1], bingocard[5][5] };
int value = 0;
int val;

// seed the random
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

// Randomize each column for each row
for (row; row <= 5; row++) {
    for (column; column <= 5; column++) {                       
        if (row == 1) {
            if (column > 1) { // row B
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
                while (x < column) { // If column is equals to another column - randomize will continue execute until it is not
                    while (bingocard[row][column] == bingocard[row][x]) { 
                        randomize(&value, row);
                        bingocard[row][column] = value;
                        value = 0;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
            else {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
            }
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (row == 2) { // row I
            if (column > 1) {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
                while (x < column) { // If column is equals to another column - randomize will continue execute until it is not
                    while (bingocard[row][column] == bingocard[row][x]) { 
                        randomize(&value, row);
                        bingocard[row][column] = value;
                        value = 0;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
            else {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
            }
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (row == 3) { // row N
            if (column > 1) {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
                while (x < column) { // If column is equals to another column - randomize will continue execute until it is not
                    while (bingocard[row][column] == bingocard[row][x]) {
                        randomize(&value, row);
                        bingocard[row][column] = value;
                        value = 0;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
            else {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
            }
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (row == 4) { // row G
            if (column > 1) {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
                while (x < column) { // If column is equals to another column - randomize will continue execute until it is not
                    while (bingocard[row][column] == bingocard[row][x]) {
                        randomize(&value, row);
                        bingocard[row][column] = value;
                        value = 0;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
            else {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
            }
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (row == 5) { // row O
            if (column > 1) {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
                while (x < column) { // If column is equals to another column - randomize will continue execute until it is not
                    while (bingocard[row][column] == bingocard[row][x]) {
                        randomize(&value, row);
                        bingocard[row][column] = value;
                        value = 0;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
            else {
                randomize(&value, row);
                bingocard[row][column] = value;
                value = 0;
            }
            x = 1;
        }
    }
    x = 1;
    column = 0;
}

printf("\nB\t| I\t |N\t |G\t|O\n");
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    printf("\n%d\t| %d\t |%d\t |%d\t| %d\n",bingocard[1][i],bingocard[2][i], bingocard[3][i], 
bingocard[4][i], bingocard[5][i]);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole code or at least a subset that would independently compile. For instance, what is randomize?

Comment: Hint : you should use an init function to fill your BINGO arrays, don't write directly the values in the code

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I won't provide full code, but here's a suggestion. Take the `B`,`I`,`N`,`G`,`O` arrays and shuffle them. Then, filling in the bingo card is as simple as taking the first 5 items from the shuffled array.

```
int B[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
shuffle_array(B, sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]));
```

Note that I did not enter a dimension for `B[]`. The compiler will calculate this. You incorrectly had `16` but there are only `15` items. Also, `sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0])` is a way to calculate the number of items in an array - in this case `15`.

`B` will now be something like:

```
15 6 8 9 4 2 11 5 12 1 10 3 13 14 7
```

Take the first 5 elements (`15 6 8 9 4`) and you're done that column. Repeat for others.

As far as shuffling the array, here's a simple algorithm: In a loop, pick 2 random indexes in the array and swap the values at those indexes. Repeat this 100 times or so.